# I can not get the Susy isolate-grid mixin to display my thumbnail gallery properly

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

I have had to use the `+isolate-grid` Susy mixin to correct some [subpixel rounding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545194/weird-misalignment-in-my-susy-layout?rq=1) and also [make 4 tiles show up in one row of a thumbnail gallery grid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796385/margin-right-not-respecting-my-gutter-value-in-susy/16839402#16839402)

Now I am facing a problem with `+isolate-grid`. It seems when I apply `+isolate-grid(2,4)` to `.tile` in my default mobile style section of my `style.sass` file, it messed up my two other break points : `tablet` and `desktop`.

The tile grid in the mobile default state looks fine:

**Mobile (default)**

[image]

but the tile grid in the `desktop` and `tablet` states are not consistent. There should be three tiles per row. Now it just looks random:

**Tablet**

[image]

**Desktop**

[image]

If I replace `+isolate-grid(2,4)` with `+span-columns(2)` in `.tile` in my default mobile style. Then the `tablet` and `desktop` states work fine but there is only one tile per row in the mobile state. There should be 2 tiles per row:

**Mobile (default)**

[image]

**Tablet**

[image]

**Desktop**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
@import compass
@import susy
@import normalize

$total-columns  : 4
$column-width   : 60px            
$gutter-width   : 20px           
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width

$container-style: fluid

$tablet : 9
$desktop : 14

// Susy-grid-background override to draw out horizontal lines
=susy-grid-background       
  +grid-background($total-columns, $column-width, $gutter-width, $base-line-height, $gutter-width, $force-fluid: true) 


$base-font-size: 18px
$base-line-height: 30px
+establish-baseline

ul
  background-color: rgb(111, 50%, 250)

li
  background: rgba(200,50,0,.2)
  text-align: right     

img
  width: 100%

h1
  +adjust-font-size-to(90px)
  +adjust-leading-to(4, 90px)
  +leader(2, 90px)
  background: rgb(0,20,200)

h1#logo
  +adjust-font-size-to(30px)
  +adjust-leading-to(2, 30px)
  +leader(0, 30px)

h2
  +adjust-font-size-to(25px)
  +adjust-leading-to(1, 25px)

p
  +leader(1)
  +trailer(1)  


.page, header, .pagenav, .main, .pagefoot
  +transition(all .3s ease)

/* 5 Column Layout */

.page                                
  +container($total-columns, $tablet, $desktop)
  +susy-grid-background

/* ------------------- BREAKPOINTS ---------------------------- */
/* ------------------- MOBILE (default) ------------------------*/

p
  +leader(0)

header
  +container
  position: fixed
  left: 0
  right: 0
  bottom: 0
  height: 2.3em
  background: rgba(250,250,250,.7)

  h1#logo a
    +hide-text
    float: right
    +span-columns(1)
    background: red

  .navicon
    +span-columns(1)
    background: green

  .pagenav
    +span-columns(4)
    background: rgba(150,200,250,.3)

    ul
      background: #ffccff
    li
      text-align: left

.main
  +span-columns(4)
  margin-top: 1em
  background: rgba(1,240,200,.3)

/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/

/* Here is where the problem happens ..............................................*/
/* +isolate-grid(2,4) messes up the tile flow in the tablet and desktop states.....*/
/* +span-columns(2) messes up the tile flow in the mobile state....................*/

.tile
  +isolate-grid(2, 4)
  // +span-columns(2)
  height: 206px
  margin-bottom: 1em
  background: cyan

/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
/* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PROBLEM AREA <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/

  .tile_title
    +adjust-font-size-to(15px)
    +adjust-leading-to(1, 15px)
    background: #af6   

  .tile_use
    @extend .tile_title
    +adjust-font-size-to(10px)
    +adjust-leading-to(1, 10px)

/* ------------------- TABLET ----------------------------------*/

+at-breakpoint($tablet)
  .page
    +container
    +susy-grid-background

  p
    +leader(0)

  header
    +container
    position: fixed
    left: 0
    right: 0
    bottom: 0
    height: 2.3em
    background: rgba(250,250,250,.7)

    h1#logo a
      +hide-text
      float: right
      +span-columns(2)
      background: red

    .navicon
      +span-columns(1 omega)
      background: green

    .pagenav
      +span-columns(2 omega,9)
      background: rgba(150,200,250,.3)

      ul
        background: #ffccff
      li
        text-align: left

  .main
    +span-columns(9)
    margin-top: 1em


    img 
      +span-columns(7, 9)

  .tile
    +isolate-grid(3, 9)
    height: 304px
    margin-bottom: 1em
    background: cyan

    .tile_title
      +adjust-font-size-to(25px)
      +adjust-leading-to(1, 25px)
      background: #af6   
      margin: 10px
      padding: 5px

    .tile_use
      @extend .tile_title
      +adjust-font-size-to(20px)
      +adjust-leading-to(1, 20px)



/* -------------------DESKTOP ----------------------------------*/

+at-breakpoint($desktop)
  .page
    +container
    +susy-grid-background


  header
    +container
    position: fixed
    left: 0
    right: 0
    top: 0
    height: 0
    z-index: 3

    h1#logo a
      +hide-text
      float: right
      +span-columns(2)
      background: red

    .pagenav
      clear: both
      float: right
      +span-columns(2)
      background: rgba(150,200,250,.3)

  .main
    +span-columns(12 omega)
    +leader(2)
    z-index: 1
    position: relative
    background: rgba(1,240,200,.3)

    img 
      +span-columns(10, 14)

  .tile
    +isolate-grid(4, 12)
    height: 304px
    margin-bottom: 1em

    .tile_title
      +adjust-font-size-to(25px)
      +adjust-leading-to(1, 25px)
      background: #af6   
      margin: 10px
      padding: 5px

    .tile_use
      @extend .tile_title
      +adjust-font-size-to(20px)
      +adjust-leading-to(1, 20px)
```

Comment: What version of Susy are you using? This was fixed in 1.0.9.

Comment: `gem list` returned `susy (1.0.8, 1.0.5, 1.0)`. ok I just installed the new Susy and the problem is solved. `+isolate-grid(2, 4)` now works. Thanks Eric!

Comment: Fantastic examples in your question!

Comment: Thank you and I hope they helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Susy issue was fixed in version 1.0.9 so I just had to update Susy to 1.0.9.
`+isolate-grid(2, 4)` now works fine.